# Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io #10060

Tags: php, email-verification, laravel-5.7

I am using Laravel 5.7 email verification but keep getting the below error after registering the user.
Can you help please?

> Swift_TransportException
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]

**This is my .env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=2525

MAIL_USERNAME=be55f77**f7e10

MAIL_PASSWORD=dbbeac8**5588d

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SSL or TLS with SMTP. MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl or tls

Port for SSL is 465.
Port for TLS is 587.

Comment: Hi Kerem, thanks for your answer. I tried both options but still getting the same error

Comment: Hello, any solution for this?